# Combining audio files in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a **HTML page** which has two audio files ABC.mp3 of 30 sec and XYZ.mp3 of 15 sec. I need to combine these two files in such a manner that I get a new file PQR.mp3 of 30 sec (AND NOT 45 sec) which has **one file overlapped/merged over the other**.
Any kind of plug-ins, javascript etc. will be helpful, keeping HTML and HTML5 under consideration.

Comment: This sounds *way* out of scope for JavaScript / HTML. Can you not use a server-side language?

Comment: @Pekka웃 how would you accomplish this with lets say PHP ? Any examples?

Comment: @trainoasis see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803130/combine-an-unknown-number-of-mp3-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164562/combine-concatenate-mp3s-on-server-using-php

Comment: @Pekka웃 unfortunately this concatenates the files only... I need to combine/merge ...

Comment: @trainoasis see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580807/merging-mp3-files-in-linux-debian-using-php

Comment: @Pekka웃 ahh, I thought I ll need to use Sox eventually. (don't have sudo access to server for installation; that's why I wanted a workaround) - thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No. Neither Javascript nor HTML5 have the power to do this. You will need server side tools to do this. For example ffmpeg and LAME in case of MP3.

If you really need to do such manipulations on a HTML basis, the only way is to bind these programms to a php script or NodeJS server that then starts a job to do what you want to do. Nevertheless you would have to write bash script or cronejobs to do so.

**edit**

For [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) you will need to write your own node server application. The application then should be using [socketIO](http://socket.io/) and [node-fluent-ffmpg](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) which also has lame with it. The app could look like this

*server:*

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('mergeFiles', function (data) {
    var firstFile = data.firstFile;
    var secondFile = data.secondFile;

    //do ffmpg stuff by executing a shell script
    execString = "./yourscript.sh " + firstFile + " " + secondFile

    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
    exec(execString , puts);
});
```

*client:*

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var firstFile = ABC.mp3;
  var secondFile = XYZ.mp3;

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.emit('mergeFiles', { firstFile: firstFile, secondFile: secondFile });
</script>
```

Comment: Any specific link of NodeJS? or any tutorial of ffmpeg or LAME which specifically does this?