# Combine an unknown number of .mp3 files

Tags: php, mp3, file-get-contents

I have this:

```
$number = 1;
$mp3 = file_get_contents("http://example.com/text=".$value);
$file = md5($value)."-".$number.".mp3";
file_put_contents($file, $mp3);
$number++;
```

Result: create `abcdef-1.mp3`, `abcdef-2.mp3`, `abcdef-3.mp3`.
Now I want to combine `abcdef-1.mp3` with `abcdef-2.mp3` and `abcdef-3.mp3`.

This works:

```
file_put_contents('abcdef.mp3',
file_get_contents('abcdef-1.mp3') .
file_get_contents('abcdef-2.mp3') .
file_get_contents('abcdef-3.mp3'));
```

But is not suitable for my code, because `abcdef` differ. Numbers too.

I've tried:

```
$number = 1;
$mp3 = file_get_contents("http://example.com/text=".$value);
$file = md5($value)."-".$number.".mp3";
file_put_contents($file, $mp3);
file_put_contents(md5($value).".mp3", file_get_contents($file));
$number++;
```

Result: create `abcdef-1.mp3`, `abcdef-2.mp3`, `abcdef-3.mp3` and `abcdef.mp3` but when I play it's only `abcdef-1.mp3`.
Where is the problem?

Comment: You can't simply join together MP3 files like that. There is header data at the beginning of each file that defines the characteristics of the audio data. You will need to re-encode those files with a full MP3 encoder.

Comment: @TimDorr: Actually, you can! Unlike most other media formats, MP3 doesn't have a container header; it's just a raw stream with optional embedded metadata at the beginning and end (which decoders are required to read and ignore). Don't try this with other formats, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call file_put_contents with the FILE APPEND flag. Something like this should work

```
$number = 1;
$mp3 = file_get_contents("http://example.com/text=".$value);
$file = md5($value).".mp3";
file_put_contents($file, $mp3, FILE_APPEND);
$number++;
```

Comment: I need to keep `$number` there for the rest of the code. Otherwise it doesn't work. It is possible?

Comment: Where do you want to keep $number?

Comment: When I save files I need to keep $number there and after that to combine. Without numbers (_1, _2, _3 etc) the rest of the code does not work.

Comment: Then you could just use my code, but instead add another file_put_content function, that looks like
file_put_contents(md5($value)."-".$number.".mp3", $mp3);